# SyncSvcUtilUI can't read its own sync configuration

Tags: c#, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I tried to use Microsoft's Syn Framework Toolkit: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23217

And as I intend to use an Android client, I also downloaded the Toolkit for it: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e

I installed the SDK, then extracted the Toolkit and built it with VS.
Following the instruction in the help file, I used SyncSvcUtilUI to create a Sync configuration file. It went through as planned.

The next step would be to use that configuration file to provision the database. After I select the aforementioned Sync configuration file, I get this message:

```
Running SyncSvcUtil command...
Invalid parameter passed
Parameter name: Sync
```

Aren't the two applications compatible with each other? What should I check? The two executables are in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directory that contained SyncSvcUtilUI had *space* in its name. After moving it to a simple directory, it worked. Great software design...